# How can I efficiently group several columns into one list column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Hello I have a table with several columns, and I'd like to "group" them all into one column of lists, each row will contain the list all values of the "grouped" columns on the same row.

- Is there a fast way of doing this with data.table
- How can I then "ungroup"

example (slow)

```
library(data.table)
library(foreach)
# create table
DT <- data.table(x_1 = 1:101, x_2 = 101:201, x_3 = 201:301, y_1 = 1:101, y_2 = 101:201)[, IDX := .I]

# we want to "condense" all x_[0-9] together and all y_[0-9]together
foreach(prefix = c("x", "y")) %do% {
    # get columns matching x_[0-9]
    cols_i <- grep(colnames(DT), pattern = sprintf("%s_[0-9]+", prefix), value = TRUE)
    # subset table
    DT_i <- DT[, c("IDX", cols_i), with = FALSE]
    # melt
    DT_i <- melt(DT_i, id.vars = "IDX")
    setkey(DT_i, IDX, variable)
    # reagglomerate
    DT_i <- DT_i[, .(value = list(value)), keyby = IDX]
    setnames(DT_i, old = "value", new = prefix)
} -> DT
DT <- Reduce(f = function(X, Y) X[Y, on = "IDX"], x = DT)
```

expected:

```
     IDX           x       y
  1:   1   1,101,201   1,101
  2:   2   2,102,202   2,102
  3:   3   3,103,203   3,103
  4:   4   4,104,204   4,104
  5:   5   5,105,205   5,105
 ---                        
 97:  97  97,197,297  97,197
 98:  98  98,198,298  98,198
 99:  99  99,199,299  99,199
100: 100 100,200,300 100,200
101: 101 101,201,301 101,201
```

Comment: What's the end use of this? Nesting and unnesting is always going to have a performance hit.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for `data.frame` in `base R`, but I believe it can also work for `data.table`:

```
df <- data.frame(IDX = 1:101, x_1 = 1:101, x_2 = 101:201, x_3 = 201:301, y_1 = 1:101, y_2 = 101:201)

res <- data.table(df[,1], Reduce(rbind,apply(df[,-1], 1, function(v) {
  data.table(x = list(as.numeric(v[grep("x",names(v))])), y = list(as.numeric(v[grep("y",names(v))])))
})))
```

such that

```
> head(res)
  IDX         x     y
1   1 1,101,201 1,101
2   2 2,102,202 2,102
3   3 3,103,203 3,103
4   4 4,104,204 4,104
5   5 5,105,205 5,105
6   6 6,106,206 6,106
```

*DATA*:

```
df <- data.frame(IDX = 1:101, x_1 = 1:101, x_2 = 101:201, x_3 = 201:301, y_1 = 1:101, y_2 = 101:201)
```

- **UPDATE 1**: with `data.table()`, but maybe slow for large dataset

```
res <- data.table(dt[,1], Reduce(rbind,apply(dt[,-1], 1, function(v) {
  data.table(x = list(v[grep("x",names(v))]), y = list(v[grep("y",names(v))]))
})))
```

such that

```
> res
     IDX           x       y
  1:   1   1,101,201   1,101
  2:   2   2,102,202   2,102
  3:   3   3,103,203   3,103
  4:   4   4,104,204   4,104
  5:   5   5,105,205   5,105
 ---                        
 97:  97  97,197,297  97,197
 98:  98  98,198,298  98,198
 99:  99  99,199,299  99,199
100: 100 100,200,300 100,200
101: 101 101,201,301 101,201
```

*DATA*:

```
dt <- data.table(IDX = 1:101, x_1 = 1:101, x_2 = 101:201, x_3 = 201:301, y_1 = 1:101, y_2 = 101:201)
```

- **UPDATE 2**: should be much faster than last update for large dataset

```
res <- cbind(dt[,1], 
             data.table(
               x = split(as.matrix(dt[,grep("x",names(dt)), with = F]),seq(nrow(dt))),
               y = split(as.matrix(dt[,grep("y",names(dt)), with = F]),seq(nrow(dt)))
               )
)
```

Comment: @statquant do you mean, for example, "1,101,201" as a `list` in the field `x`?

Comment: I am afraid this would be very slow if data was real-life size :(

Comment: @statquant Yes, that's true. I will be very slow when with large dataset due to `apply()`...I will try to find other solution

Comment: @statquant you can try the solution in `UPDATE 2`, which could be much faster

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that relies on `asplit()` which splits a matrix by rows:

```
DT[, X := asplit(as.matrix(.SD), 1), .SDcols = grep('x', names(DT))]
DT[, Y := asplit(as.matrix(.SD), 1), .SDcols = grep('y', names(DT))]
```

It would likely have similar performance to @ThomasIsCoding

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following. Although all variables are kept in this solution, you can of course just subset the final `DT` for columns `IDX, X and Y`, i.e. `DT[, .(IDX, X, Y)]`.

**Code**

```
xcols = colnames(DT)[colnames(DT) %like% 'x']
ycols = colnames(DT)[colnames(DT) %like% 'y']

DT[, X := lapply(IDX, function(x){
  lapply(xcols, function(y) DT[x, get(y)])
})]

DT[, Y := lapply(IDX, function(x){
  lapply(ycols, function(y) DT[x, get(y)])
})]
```

**Output**

```
> dput(head(DT))

structure(list(x_1 = 1:6, x_2 = 101:106, x_3 = 201:206, y_1 = 1:6, 
               y_2 = 101:106, IDX = 1:6, 
               X = list(list(1L, 101L, 201L), list(2L, 102L, 202L), list(3L, 103L, 203L), list(4L, 104L, 204L), list(5L, 105L, 205L), list(6L, 106L, 206L)), 
               Y = list(list(1L, 101L), list(2L, 102L), list(3L, 103L), list(4L, 104L), list(5L, 105L), list(6L, 106L))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
               class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
              .Names = c("x_1", "x_2", "x_3", "y_1", "y_2", "IDX", "X", "Y"))
```